# Transmission of data between client / server using sockets

Tags: c, sockets, server

I'm doing an internship on a fleet management company that uses *car tracking* [devices](https://teltonika-gps.com/product/fmb140/) to pinpoint drivers (that work for big corporations) via *GPS*.

My project consists in integrating *Bluetooth* sensors ([temperature](https://teltonika-gps.com/product/blue-puck-t/#features) and [humidity](https://plantron.gr/download/manuals/Tzone/TZ-BT04.pdf), mainly) with those said devices.

I had no trouble integrating all the devices (since we have a *[software](https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/FMB140_Configuration)* that basically does everything for us, all we need to do is configure it properly). This *software* sends the device's information (coordinates, I/O values received, etc.) to a server and a port, defined by us.

Even though my project consists mainly on *hardware*, I would like to design a simple code to create a more robust solution (it helps me having a better grade as well since I'm developing my project even further).

My idea was to create a code (to be applied on the company's server) that would listen to information and store it on / using sockets. From what I recall, I have to establish a connection using sockets, listen to the information, accept it and then store it.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
// Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming 

#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 6027

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
struct sockaddr_in address;
int opt = 1;
int addrlen = sizeof(address);
char buffer[1024] = {0};

// Creating socket file descriptor

if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == 0) {
    perror("socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Force attach socket to PORT 6027

if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 

if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) {
    perror("bind failed"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}

if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) {
    perror("listen"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) {
    perror("accept"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024); 
printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

I visited [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/) website in order to follow some instructions on how to create the server side code. Would like to hear if there's anything missing / wrong and how to fix it!

Comment: Check out https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/, it should answer any questions you have about sockets.

Comment: So it looks like you copied the server side code...if it compiles and runs (and then just sits there), you probably did that part right.  Have you tried copying, compiling and running the client side code?  If you run the client while the server is running, the server should receive the message and print it out.  Does that happen?  If not, you need to describe what is happening, what you expect, and ask a specific question.

Comment: Also, it helps keeping your question as specific as possible. Your questions is so generic as to be almost pointless, i.e. you are doing some things that might be wrong, but it doesn't matter if it is working for you.

Comment: @Clarus Will check the guide out. Thanks as well for the tip on keeping things simple.

Comment: @DaveM. I didn't specify it on the main post but my idea isn't really to implement this. It seems weird writting a code and not implementing it IRL but I'll explain:

The company already has a platform / server / etc. fully working. This project was designed to be implemented on a new platform (simpler, which would be created by some colleagues doing an internship there as well) but, with COVID, everything was stopped. This said, I can't implement the code on the main platform nor the new one. The idea to present a server side code was to simulate the connection, like a "case study".